# SharePoint WorkFlow 2013 publish problems

Tags: 2013, workflow

The problem:

I'm trying to publish 2013 workflow from sharepoint designer and have a error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation failed with error
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Попытка выполнить
>   несанкционированную операцию.    в
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAppPrincipalPermissionsManager.UpdateAppOnlyPolicy(SPAppPrincipalInfo
>   appPrincipal, Boolean allowAppOnlyPolicy)    в
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.SPWebWorkflowSecurityContext.b__3()
>   в Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.

With 2010 workflows all works.

Get this problem on one site, on all others all work fine.

Any advise to solve problem?

[image]

Update:

Site actions > Site Settings > Site features > Workflows can use app permissions

User have full access to this site and have administrator access but SP says that there no permissions to deactivate/activate it.

Answer (score 1):

already answered before:

> Site actions > Site Settings > Site features > Workflows can use app
>   permissions

[SPD 2013 Workflow fails when started with System Account Credentials](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74048/spd-2013-workflow-fails-when-started-with-system-account-credentials?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the workflow doesn’t have permissions to access the list where the Workflows generally run at permission level equivalent to write. In this case, you need to elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013 as the following:

- Make sure that the login user has a sufficient permission as a site collection administrator.
- Make sure that you have configured `App Management Service` as mentioned at [Sorry, something went wrong App Management Shared Service Proxy is not installed in SharePoint Server 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/26/create-and-configure-app-management-service-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)
- Allow workflow to use app permissions by activating `Workflows can use app permissions`.
- Grant full control permission to a workflow by configuring `site app permission`.
- Write your actions inside an `App Step` using SharePoint Designer.

For more details, Check my article with the detail steps at [Elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)